# Magento multi store copy content from one website to another

Tags: magento-1.9, product, multistore, multi-website

I am new to magento and I have multi store setup in magento 1.9.2.1 where I have **retail** and **Wholesale** website setuped. There are data on **Wholesale** website where user can login and see products. Product prices are set as per users, i.e. If user A login then he see different price and if user B login then he see defferent price then user A.

So how I copy all data of **user A** to **retail** website.
Both website share same dashboard. (one dashboard)
[image]

Comment: Which data you want to copy  ??

Comment: @Arunendra Product data

Comment: How did you done  Symbolic link for multi website.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to copy userdata to other website.You can **share customer data** **globally** in magneto.Then  if customer register any of the store can have access to login any store with same details.

To enable this go to:

```
admin panel > system > configuration > customer configuration > Account Sharing Option > Share Customer Accounts > Global
```